# Javascript and Rails Filters and Sorting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails, and don't know much javascript. I have a model called "pieces", and `piece` has a `genre`, a `title` and a `price`. On my index page, I have buttons at the top that are supposed to filter the pieces by genre, and then sort those pieces by price increasing, price decreasing, or alphabetically by title. Note: right now, the genres can only be 'option1' and 'option2'. I have no idea how to do this. Thanks!

Index.html.erb

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="center">
    <h1>Listing Pieces</h1>
  </div>


  <!-- Sort and filter buttons start -->
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Filter and Sort">

    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Filter By Genre
        <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">option1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">option2</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>  

    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Sort By
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Price $-$$</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Price $$-$</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

 </div> <!-- Sort and filter buttons end -->

 <div id="pieces" class="transitions-enabled">
   <% @pieces.each do |piece| %>
     <div class="box panel panel-default">
       <%= link_to image_tag(piece.image.url(:medium)), piece %>

       <div class="panel-body">
         <%= piece.title %><br/>
         <%= piece.genre %><br/>
         $<%= piece.price%>
       </div>
     </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Also, not sure if this is relevant, but I am using jQuery masonry to animate the movement of the pieces.

pieces.cofee

```
$ ->
    $('#pieces').imagesLoaded ->
        $('#pieces').masonry
            itemSelector: '.box'
            isFitWidth: true
```

Comment: Use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to present your index as a sortable table. It's dead easy to use, and it's so handy that you'll find yourself using it throughout your app. If you prefer a gem, you can get it [here](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails).

Comment: it's great that you're using masonry (it's a smart approach to grids) but you have to explicate you question a bit more clearly. It's not apparent where the specific problem is or what concept you're struggling with

Comment: @MarsAtomic I don't want the index page to be a data table. Each piece is represented on the index page as a panel - it looks sort of like pinterest. By filtering, I just want the panels that don't have that attribute to disappear, and then sort those panels by the criteria listed above. Does that answer the question?

Comment: @maxpleaner Each piece is represented on the index page as a panel - it looks sort of like pinterest. By filtering, I just want the panels that don't have that attribute to disappear, and then sort those panels by the criteria listed above. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Yeah sounds like you want the isotope library

Comment: @maxpleaner Yes, this is the functionality I want. But is there a way to do this with plain javascript or jquery? I don't want to pay $25 a month for the isotope library.

Comment: Where are you getting $25 a month. It's free for open-source projects ... there's a one time $25 charge for _commercial_ projects. You can just download the script and use it. I just build something with this, see [https://maxpleaner.github.io/mindless/](https://maxpleaner.github.io/mindless/)

Comment: @maxpleaner ok, thanks